# Filtering nested list is not bringing back the correct result set

Tags: c#, linq

I currently have a list of skills which looks something like:

```
var list = new List<Test>
    {
        new Test
        {
            Name = "Some Name",
            Skills = new List<Skill>
            {
                new Skill { SkillName = "Java" },
                new Skill { SkillName = "JavaScript" },
                new Skill { SkillName = "C#" },
                new Skill { SkillName = "CSS" }
            }
        }
    };
```

Now, I am trying to filter the result by the search term `Java` for which the code looks something like:

```
var searchTerm = "Java";
    
var filteredList = list.Where(t => t.Skills.Any(s => s.SkillName.Contains(searchTerm))).ToList();
```

Here, I would expect the filteredList to contain `Java` & `JavaScript` but it's bringing back all the 4 items. Does anyone know where I'm going wrong?

[dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/c1aIYH)

Comment: What do you want `filteredList` to contain? A collection of tests or skills?

Comment: @peinearydevelopment I want the `filteredList` to contain the collection of test and skills collection which is filtered to two items in this case `Java` & `JavaScript` if that's possible

Comment: Note that creating a new `Test` item with a filtered member `Skills` is unlikely to be what you really want to do (e.g. any changes in `Test` will not apply to the original).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new list to achieve this. You could do this as follows:

```
var filteredList =
    // where filters down the list to the tests you are interested in(ones containing a skill that has the search term)
    list.Where(t => t.Skills.Any(s => s.SkillName.Contains(searchTerm)))
        // select creates a new list, where each test only has the skills that match the search term
        .Select(t => new Test
                     {
                       Name = t.Name,
                       Skills = t.Skills.Where(s => s.SkillName.Contains(searchTerm)).ToList()
                     })
        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

In your query `Where` operator applies to the list of tests only.
You need something like:

```c#
var searchTerm = "Java";
    
var filteredList = list
    .Where(t => t.Skills.Any(s => s.SkillName.Contains(searchTerm)))
    .Select(t => new Test
        {
            Name = t.Name,
            Skills = t.Skills
                .Where(s => s.SkillName.Contains(searchTerm))
                .ToList()
        })
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is about retrieving the `Test` objects where the `Skills` property contains an item where the skillname contains your search term. Since you return the full `Test` object, you're seeing the unaltered list.

You need to reassign the nested `Skills` property to a list with just the terms you looked for.